# How to install a python version using pyenv/pyenv-win in microsoft windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, pyenv, multiple-versions

### TLDR

I cannot install 3.6.10 using pyenv-win and can install 3.6.8 only [ref](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/100).

Though I cannot get it become global python version using `pyenv global` [ref](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/100#issuecomment-626516225)

### Details

I installed pyenv-win as guided [here](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win#installation) and failed as below output. As you know the fix, please share.

p.s. I also post this on pyenv-win github home [here](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/100)

> :: [ERROR] :: 404 :: file not found

My full command and output as below

```
PS C:\Users\namgivu> pyenv install 3.6.10
:: [Info] ::  Mirror: https://www.python.org/ftp/python
:: [Downloading] ::  3.6.10 ...
:: [Downloading] ::  From https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.10/python-3.6.10.exe
:: [Downloading] ::  To   C:\Users\namgivu\.pyenv\pyenv-win\install_cache\python-3.6.10.exe
:: [ERROR] :: 404 :: file not found
```

---

Retried with 3.6.8 and can succeed; though CANNOT `pyenv global` set it to have my windows os to use this 3.6.8 globally instead of previously-installed 3.7.7. This issue also be discussed [here](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/100#issuecomment-626516225)

```
PS C:\Users\namgivu> pyenv install 3.6.8
:: [Info] ::  Mirror: https://www.python.org/ftp/python
:: [Downloading] ::  3.6.8 ...
:: [Downloading] ::  From https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/python-3.6.8.exe
:: [Downloading] ::  To   C:\Users\namgivu\.pyenv\pyenv-win\install_cache\python-3.6.8.exe
:: [Installing] ::  3.6.8 ...
:: [Info] :: completed! 3.6.8
PS C:\Users\namgivu> pyenv global 3.6.8
PS C:\Users\namgivu> python -V
Python 3.7.7
```

Answer (score 5):

Python [3.6.9](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-369/) and [3.6.10](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3610/) was released as source only - there is no compiled version for Windows.

You may wish to compile it yourself, but before you do, please read the good advice in this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060596/compiling-python-3-6-9-on-windows/57060827#57060827).

---

Side note for `pyenv global` command

After `pyenv install`, we need to call `pyenv rehash` before setting it global/local as discussed [here](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/100#issuecomment-626702101)

```
PS C:\Users\namgivu> pyenv global 3.7.6; pyenv rehash; python -V
Python 3.7.6
PS C:\Users\namgivu> pyenv global 3.6.8; pyenv rehash; python -V
Python 3.6.8
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try 3.6.8 then

Comment: I will add this info to the ticket on GH also.

Comment: Tried and can get 3.6.8 installed @SeanHolm